# Is a one-way manned mission to Mars currently possible?

Tags: mars, colonization, future-missions, return

I read about the manned mission [here](https://www.theguardian.com/news/video/2015/feb/09/volunteers-first-manned-mission-mars-video) and I have a few questions:

1. What prevents a return trip from Mars. Why can't a spaceship with efficient fuel, food and oxygen supplies be built for a return trip?
2. How much supplies can we send to sustain human life?
3. When is a manned mission necessary rather then sending robots like Curiosity to do research on the planet?

Comment: Hi martian87.  That's many question you're asking.  On this website, please ask one question per post!

Comment: Also, please research the site before opening questions, I suspect most of these have already been answered

Comment: You can search through the questions and answers in our library using the search box on the right side of the menu bar. A search for 'Mars One' is the most relevant, also try 'crewed missions'. Also note the top four questions in the Related list in the right sidebar (if you are not on a mobile device) are all relevant.

Comment: 1. No, right now there is no infrastructure (or budget to setup one) for a spaceship construction on Mars. There are potentially other ways to approach the return trip, but none of those are currently configured or budgeted either. 2. Not enough data - it depends heavily on the mission configuration and the effects of the environment on human lifespan. 3. Varied - there are many different ways they could die depending on mission configuration, environment, etc. 4. It's not, but it is. Those that support human colonization of space say we need a sustained human presence off-world.

Comment: And that comment should demonstrate how many different angles you need to address. Start with number 4: do some research on our site and you can find some answers. Once you understand why people are there, you will understand that death is inevitable (assuming immortality is not an option). Then you can research number 1, which I believe has also been answered here already.

Comment: I think the current title contradicts the question content...

Answer (score 8):

Getting back is not impossible, just very expensive.

[image: one Falcon Heavy to get there, ten Saturn V to get there and back again]

[This site](https://what-if.xkcd.com/38/) has a good explanation of the phenomenon.

Comment: I think this answers all of this well and is not to broad.